# How to make collection-editing control without initializing state from props and not using flux?

Tags: reactjs

So I have a fairly straightforward control where you get as props a list of email addresses and you generate a list of input boxes for each with the additional ability to add an email inbox or remove the existing inboxes.

So the way this works conceptually is

- Initialize state array from the props array
- For each string in the state

  - Generate an email input with defaultValue from the current item
  - Generate a remove button. When clicked remove item at this index from state array
- Generate an add button. When clicked add a new empty string to state array

I understand how the whole flux model is supposed to work with this sending events upstream and re-rendering props. However **I am not using a flux-flavored anything here**. It's a simple html form.

What is the right way to implement this that does not [intitialize state from props](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)?

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to pass down a prop like `initialValues` for example, and set that as the default state in `getInitialState`. Then it's clear that the prop is just used as the initial state (it's set once, when the component mounts) and that the actual state is the responsibility of the component itself.

There's an entry on dealing with forms in the React documentation which might be helpful:

> https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: Yes, I read that many times, but what happens when you *add* or *remove*? That backing model change has to be reflected somewhere or render will not generate the proper input. Because I'm not using flux (the main model doesn't care about this) it must be in the state  - so what goes in state if not a copy of props that I modify? And then I'm initializing state from props...

Comment: Decide where the state belongs, when you add or remove, can't you mutate the state of the root/parent component where the props with the default state comes from?

Comment: Why would the state not belong in this component?

Comment: If the state belongs to the component, then you can just add/remove array entries from the component state, or am I missing something here?

Comment: In my question see step 1. That is required for this approach. It is also explicitly recommended against by the linked guidance from Facebook.

Comment: it's fine when a prop is used for initializing *just* default values, not as a source of truth in the components lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the *correct* answer. In this approach you would make state an array of "user actions" eg.

```
[
   {action: 'add'},
   {action: 'modify', index: 1, newValue: 'fred.flinstone@brock.com'},
   {action: 'modify', index: 2, newValue: 'barney.rubble@brock.com'},
   {action: 'remove', index: 0},
]
```

Clicking a button or changing an input would add an entry to this array.
Your binding for each property then would take the initial props, and reduce down the state actions to figure out what the current state is currently.

Now that is the version that *feels right*. It's also a lot of work. As @Eelke pointed out, the guidance has a caveat for when your props isn't the "current" state, so much as the "initial state". With that being the case I think it actually *does* make sense to initialize state from props here.